# returning 'A' DNS record in dnspython

Tags: python, dns, domain-name, dnspython

I am using [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/) to get the 'A' record and return the result (IP address for a given domain).

I have this simple testing python script:

```
import dns.resolver

def resolveDNS():
    domain = "google.com" 
    resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver(); 
    answer = resolver.query(domain , "A")
    return answer

resultDNS = resolveDNS()
print resultDNS
```

However, the output is:

```
<dns.resolver.Answer object at 0x0000000004F56C50>
```

I need to get the result as a string. If it is an array of strings, how to return it?

Comment: have u tried `for item in resultDNS: print item`? I think that would give u a fair idea whats inside the returned object and how its elements can be accessed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import dns.resolver

def resolveDNS():
    domain = "google.com" 
    resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver(); 
    answer = resolver.query(domain , "A")
    return answer

resultDNS = resolveDNS()
answer = ''

for item in resultDNS:
    resultant_str = ','.join([str(item), answer])

print resultant_str
```

So now the `resultant_str` is a variable of type string that holds A records separated by comma.

Answer (score 8):

The answer(s) you get is actually an iterator of 'A' records, so you'll need to iterate through those:

```
answers = resolver.query(domain, 'A')
for answer in answers:
    print (answer.to_text())
```